# Colocar imagem para representar arquivo dependendo da extensão com CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Boa noite, é possível eu personalizar a aparência de um arquivo exibido dependendo do tipo da extensão (docx, pdf, xlsx) com CSS?

Por exemplo, eu exibo os meus arquivos que esta em um diretório através de um `href`, quero que quando for um arquivo WORD, exiba uma imagem do WORD e o nome do arquivo logo abaixo, de preferência dentro da imagem, como posso estar fazendo isso?

**Código:**

```
<?php

require('conexaobd.php');

$sql = "SELECT relatorio.*, pacientes.nome, pacientes.data_saida FROM relatorio,pacientes WHERE relatorio.paciente=pacientes.nome";

$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$inc = 0;

while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {


echo '
    <tr>
        echo $cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica'] != "" ? "<td><a href='ver-arquivo.php?documento=uploads/uploadsed/{$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']}' title='{$cont['relatorio_educacao_fisica']}' target='_blank'></a></td>" : "<td></td>";           
    ';
}

?>
```